# Designing and printing a receipt format in flex

Tags: flex4, flash-builder

I want to design a **Receipt** in flex.

Which control shall I use to display a table if I want to display some table cells without border? I also want to merge cells in the table just as we used to do in Excel.

Can anyone please give me the code to print the Receipt upon the button click?

Answer (score 0):

I would probable use a List control with a customItemRenderer or a textArea with some fancy text formatting. As for giving you the code, I would be happy to provide input to code you have done or point you in the right direction but cant do your work for you. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please prepare your receipt layout in flex and just check your layout is proper or not. if it proper then put one button and write down the printjob code on click event of the button. be sure at the time of click event please hide the button till printing is done (means upto send method called)

please refer PrintJob Class of ActionScript for your application to get receipt printing through your flex application.